# php regex: or clause doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

i need to write a regex for make a double check: if a string contains empty spaces at the beginning, at the end, and if all string it's composed by empty spaces, and if string contains only number.
I've write this regex

```
 $regex = '/^(\s+ )| ^(\d+)$/';
```

but it doesn't' work. What's wrong ?

Comment: Your question is confusing... how can it be "composed by empty spaces" and be "a numeric string"?

Comment: @JeremyMiller `1` is no longer the loneliest number, `&nbsp;` is...

Comment: edited. I mean a string composed only by numbers :)

Comment: @giozh Give several examples of good and bad strings: 1 for each condition. Many people are confused.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you checking if a string is made only of empty spaces or only numbers? what do empty spaces at the beginning and the end do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: get your spaces right!
For example `(\s+ )` will match a minimum of one space (`\s+`) followed by another space ()! Same applies for the space between `|` and `^`. This way you will match the space literally every time and this leads to wrong results.

If I get you right and you want to match on strings which

- start with one or more spaces OR
- end with one or more spaces OR
- consist only of spaces OR
- consist only of numbers

I'd use

```
/^(?:\s+.*|.*\s+$|\d+$)/
```

[Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uM6yL8)

This way you match spaces at the start of the string (`\s+.*`) or (`|`) spaces at the end of the string (`.*\s+$`) or a completely numeric string (`\d+$`).
Insert capturing groups as needed.

This will match in case the whole string consists of spaces, too, because technically the string then starts with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The space before `^(\d+)` make your regex can't catch the numeric string.

It should be like below:

```
$regex = '/^\s*\d*\s*$/';
```

Answer (score 1):

First if all, remove the space between | and ^. You are trying to match a space **before** the beginning of the line (^), so that can not work.

I do not exactly understand what you want. Either a string that only consists of white spaces, or a number that may have white spaces at the beginning or end? Try this:

```
$regex = '/^\s*\d*\s*$/';
```